# Swift | UIBarButton not working / not going to action target

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

so i made a custom UIBarButtonItem outside the class and set its properties.
 i added it to the navigation controller in a seperate method which is called from viewDidLoad().  the target for the button is declared inside the class itself . 
I even tried adding a break point  at the target method to make sure it works but as it turns out the button does not go to the target and takes tap despite the break points.
I have made all the code programmatically.

I tried the answers for this questions on stackoverflow but didnt work.

when i declare the button inside the viewDidLoad, the target does recognise the button and the button is also not displayed.

Thanks in advance , below is the code for the same

```
// inside class but outside viewDidLoad
    let volumeButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "speaker"), style: UIBarButtonItem.Style.plain , target: self, action: #selector(volumeButtonTapped(_ :)))

//// inside a custom method which is called from viewDidLoad()
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = volumeButton

//// below is the target declared inside the class
@objc func volumeButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if volume=="loud"{
        volume = "mute"
        volumeButton.image = UIImage(named: "mute")
        print("volume set to mute")
        //UserDefaults.standard.set(volume, forKey: "mute")
    }
     if volume == "mute"{
        volume = "loud"
        volumeButton.image = UIImage(named: "speaker")
        print("volume set to loud")
        //UserDefaults.standard.set(volume, forKey: "speaker")
    }
}
```

Comment: You inherited from `UINavigationController` and overridden `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: i added navigationcontroller in AppDelegate like this  :     var navigationController: UINavigationController?
 and yes viewDidLoad is overriden and everything else works fine

Comment: Can you show a declaration of class with your custom `viewDidLoad`?
Like `class Name: Something`

Comment: Is it possible that you can't see this button because `speaker` image doesn't exist?

Comment: i can see the button, image exists and gets tap like a button would just not go the target and here is declaration of the class 
class NewTableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource , UINavigationBarDelegate , UINavigationControllerDelegate

Comment: `volumeButtonTapped` declared outside of `NewTableViewController`?

Comment: no it is inside the class but outside the viewDidLoad

Comment: Next problem which I see is that there are two if statements inside objc method. You change text in first and then second is executed so you always run through both if statements. You should use `else if` for second condition instead

Comment: well i tried with else if and didnt work and also dont forget that that it is not even going to the break point set at the target

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The target (`self`) is still `nil` when you initialize the `volumeButton` like you do. Make the button a `lazy var` instead:

```
lazy var volumeButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "speaker"), style: .plain , target: self, action: #selector(volumeButtonTapped))
```

As @Robert Dresler stated you also have to replace the second `if` statement in the `volumeButtonTapped` function with an `else if` to make your code work - although this has nothing to do with the target action problem.

You could also make your code a little bit cleaner by using a solution similar to this:

```
var deviceIsMuted = false {
    didSet {
        volumeButton.image = UIImage(named: deviceIsMuted ? "mute" : "speaker")
        print("volume set to", deviceIsMuted ? "mute" : "loud")
    }
}

@objc func volumeButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    deviceIsMuted = !deviceIsMuted
}
```

Comment: THANKS so much, the lazy var worked, could you tell me why so i know in future?

Comment: In your initial code the `volumeButton` gets initialized at a point where the view controller itself (which you declare as the button's target) is still `nil`. So the button sends its action to `nil` instead of the view controller instance when pressed. With that `lazy var` the `volumeButton` gets initialized when it is first accessed in your code (if at all) instead. This definitely happens **after** the view controller has been initialized. Hope that helps.